# Hbase: Region splitting while writing to the region

Tags: hbase

My production system is `CDH3`, (old but still in use)

I have a few regions with `storefilesAizeMB` over 200K.
I want to know if I can split a region while also writing to that region?

Answer (score 0):

That's what Hbase do when the region become to big. But it is a slow process and it will affect your write perfomance.

The best practise is to presplit region based on your data model when creating the database. Here is a small code snippet:

```
HTableDescriptor desc = new HTableDescriptor(tableName); // Tablename tablename
HColumnDescriptor coldef = new HColumnDescriptor(Bytes.toBytes("CON"));
desc.addFamily(coldef); // add the cf to the table

// function to get all regions looking at the data
// it is an array which stocks the prefix of each regions
byte[][] regions = getRegions();
admin.createTable(desc, regions);
```

Comment: Can't pre-split regions when the system has been running for over 3 years.  We turned off automatically splitting and monitor.  But it is good to know I can manually split my large regions while writing to them.  Thanks

Comment: maybe you can consider transfering the data to a new cluster now that you know well your database. Having a good region balancing can improve your performance on write and reads

Comment: and for live splitting look at force splitting but I don't think it is recommanded

Answer (score 0):

the answer is NO .

> If the RegionServer is not online, or throws
>   NotServingRegionException, the master moves the region to OFFLINE
>   state and re-assigns it to a different RegionServer.

see 
https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#regions.arch.states 
and 
https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#arch.region.splits